# How to remove all items from List1 if List1’s item’s value matches id’s value in the List2 and parentId for that object is not null in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```js
List1 = ["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"];

List2 =
[
  {
    "id": "aaa",
    "parentId": null   
  },
  {
    "id": "bbb",
    "parentId": "aaa"
  },
  {
    "id": "ccc",
    "parentId": null
  },
  {
    "id": "ddd",
    "parentId": "ccc"
  }
];

code I have tried so far:
console.log(List2.filter(c => !c.parentId && List1.includes(c.id)));
```

My Ending List1 should be like:
List1 = [ "aaa",  "ccc"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
List1 = ["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"];

List2 =
[
  {
    "id": "aaa",
    "parentId": null   
  },
  {
    "id": "bbb",
    "parentId": "aaa"
  },
  {
    "id": "ccc",
    "parentId": null
  },
  {
  "id": "ddd",
  "parentId": "ccc"
  }
];

let res = List1.filter(item1 => {
  return List2.some(item2 => {
    return item2.id === item1 && !item2.parentId;
  })
})

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

If your `List1` would contain `[ "aaa", "ccc"]` then you need to find the element and  test if that element's `parentId` is null. Then only you will get the desired result.

```js
let List1 = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"];

const List2 = [{
    id: "aaa",
    parentId: null,
  },
  {
    id: "bbb",
    parentId: "aaa",
  },
  {
    id: "ccc",
    parentId: null,
  },
  {
    id: "ddd",
    parentId: "ccc",
  },
];

List1 = List1.filter((id) => {
  const isExist = List2.find((el) => el.id === id);
  if (isExist) {
    return isExist.parentId === null;
  }
  return false;
});
console.log(List1);
```

Comment: Is this your desired result, or you're looking for something different. If not, Please comment so that I can edit the answer as per your result.